# Apache loadbalancer not serving requests intelligently

Tags: apache-httpd, tomcat, load-balancing

My Apache LB is serving requests to a failed node as well. Am I missing something?

```
worker.list=node1,node3,loadbalancer

worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=10.0.0.17 
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1


worker.node3.port=8009  
worker.node3.host=10.0.0.36  
worker.node3.type=ajp13  
worker.node3.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb  
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1  
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node3  
worker.loadbalancer.socket_connect_timeout=5000  
worker.loadbalancer.ping_mode= A  
worker.loadbalancer.ping_timeout=1000  
worker.loadbalancer.fail_on_status=500,503,404,303  
Worker.loadbalancer.recover_time = 60 seconds
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the Apache load balancer, but I'll mention an inconsistency in your output -- are the trailing periods in the "node1" section in your actual config file? They are different from the ones in "node3"

Comment: Hey Sorry about that its just a typo . I do not have that trailing periods in my config file.

Answer (score 0):

You have `node1` and `node3` listed in `worker.list`. You should only mention the `loadbalancer` worker there.

See https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/workershowto.html section 'Advanced lb Worker properties' for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the Link.. After these changes I am facing another problem , even before the complete startup of my tomcat node the requests start going to the node which is under startup and then the session id gets timed out. Is there any ways that LB can route the request only once the tomcat completely starts up ?

Comment: Also the link http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html has good information about tomcat load balancers. I guess you need to tune the `ping_mode` and `ping_timeout` values for your worker nodes so tomcat can detect a failing node faster.

Comment: I did use the settings but still the session id's are getting routed to startup node. Is there a way where i can check for successful wget/curl output and then route the traffic to the started node ?

Comment: Any Help Please ?